# List folders with numerical names in a descending order based on their numerical name value

Tags: bash

Mission:
Find the *folders* that have numerical names.
List them in a *numerically-descending order* based on their *numerical name value*.

Example:
In the folder `test/` there are folders: `1` `2` `3` `10`

The code:

```
ls -al test/ | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'
```

Output: ( another problem is : it includes dots )

```
.
..
1
10
2
3
```

Desired output: ( descending order based on numerical name value )

```
10
3
2
1
```

Comment: Take a look at GNU `find` and `sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
ls -d */ |  cut -d '/' -f 1 | sort -nr
```

Output :

```
10
3
2
1
```

- `-d` list directories themselves, not their contents.
  This will list the current dir `.` so `*/` list all files in current dir.
- `cut` cut the given string.
  `-d` using delimiter `'/'` since the output is like `1/`.
  `-f 1` return the first field witch is `1`.
- `sort -nr` mean sort by numerical value in reverse order.

Or you can with your way:

```
ls -al | grep '^d' | awk 'NR>2 {print $9}' | sort -nr
```

Added `NR>2` to awk & `sort -nr` at the end. The output will be the same as above command.

Comment: In my system for "`sort`" there is no "`h`" option. ( I am currently using "SliTaz" 5.x which I believe uses Linux kernel 3.x ) . I ran "`sort --help`" and found out there was an "`n`" option,  I used "`n`" instead of "`h`" in your code, and it seems to be working. Perhaps I can select your answer as "chosen answer" if you replace "`h`" with "`n`" in your code. And also `r` option seems to equate to `Reverse sort order` in my system.

Comment: I did check and `-n` those it so I updated my answer.